# linking select with radio using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fairly new at jQuery, so I was trying to change the value of a radio box, automatically as I select an option from the from my select dropdown. But it is not going as I planned.

For eg: 
If I select Mrs. or Ms. from the select options then the property of the radio with value female should become true.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('[name="title"]').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "Ms." || $(this).val() == "Mrs.") {
        $("#female").prop("checked", true);
      } else if ($(this).val() == "Mr.") {
        $("#male").prop("checked", true);
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="title">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>
  <label>Title</label>

  <p><b>Gender</b>
    <br/>
  </p>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Wrap your code in: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ and it should work.

Comment: @nevermind thanks a lot it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be correct. Try just using a document.ready, or loading it at the end of the body.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[name="title"]').change(function() {
          if ($(this).val() == "Ms." || $(this).val() == "Mrs.") {
            $("#female").prop("checked", true);
          } else if ($(this).val() == "Mr.") {
            $("#male").prop("checked", true);
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <select name="title">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="Mr.">Mr.</option>
    <option value="Mrs.">Mrs.</option>
    <option value="Ms.">Ms.</option>
  </select>
  <label>Title</label>

  <p><b>Gender</b>
    <br/>
  </p>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
</body>

<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a document.ready line.

[Using this page as a reference](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-select-a-radio-button-with-jquery/) (which is an explanation of how to target radio buttons with jQuery), this is how I used your code to get it to work in my test environment:

```
$(document).ready(initializePage);
function initializePage(){
  $('[name="title"]').change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == "Ms." || $(this).val() == "Mrs.") {
        $('input:radio[name=gender]')[1].checked = true;
      } else if ($(this).val() == "Mr.") {
        $('input:radio[name=gender]')[0].checked = true;
      }
    });
}
```